How to Test Performance of Laravel Octane with FrankenPHP in Docker on Windows?
I recently installed Laravel Octane with FrankenPHP using Docker on my Windows machine. I want to test the performance of my Laravel application running with Octane and FrankenPHP, but I'm unsure about the best practices and tools to use for benchmarking in this specific setup. What steps should I take to effectively measure performance, including response times and resource usage?
I have set up my application and would like to conduct performance tests. I've looked into tools like Apache Bench (ab) and JMeter but have not yet implemented them. I expect to be able to identify bottlenecks in my application and see how well it performs under load. Additionally, I am looking for recommendations on the best tools and methods for performance testing in a Docker environment with Laravel Octane and FrankenPHP.
